# call and render a controller method in laravel without a redirect

Tags: exception, routes, laravel-5

#### Background

laravel currently allows you to easily define views for specific HTTP status code responses.  For example, an HTTP status code of 404 will display the `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` view automatically if it exists.  it works the same for other codes like 500 errors.

#### Problem

All of the routes on my site are processed through controllers, all of which extend a base `Controller`.  This base controller sometimes initializes the user, sets the current timezone, and other random stuff. The master template often relies on these variables. For example, if a user is logged in, the `Controller` figures that out and passes that user to the view. My master template looks for that user, and shows certain functionality if present. When a 404 is hit, I want to still be able to show the user specific menus, and continue using that 404 view.

#### Question

I submitted an issue on Github to see if we could route HTTP exceptions through controllers, but they did not agree with the proposal. So now I'm looking to see if there is a way to render a controller method when I catch an HTTP exception. I do not want to simply redirect to the appropriate route, but rather catch the exception and render the controller method.

I don't know enough about the internals of the routing, so I'm curious, is this possible? And if so, how do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible - look into the `ExceptionHandler` (under app\Exceptions), or look at implementing some [Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) to catch unknown routes.

Alternatively you can also extend the 404 view from your base template, save data in the session to present on the view or even call a `->back()` on the 404 with a flash error.

Comment: i would say that Middleware is not the appropriate place to handle exceptions. I am using the `Handler` to report and render my exceptions, and currently just render a view. do you know how to route to the controller from the handler? i do like the suggestion to flash some data and send them back. might go with that for the time being.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the `redirect()` helper is available in Handler, otherwise you have request/response objects that you can trigger a redirect from too.